# How do I combine two ordered series of different resolution in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, data-manipulation

I have some borehole geological data, ordered by depth from surface to some total depth. There are several sets that I wish to combine into one, each with different resolution. The highest resolution data set has the required output resolution (it also has evenly-spaced depths, whereas the others do not).
I have many of these to manage, so a manual spreadsheet edit is going to take too long.

For example, here are some of the high-res data at a selected depth range (about 151--152):

```
data <-
structure(list(DEPTH = c(150.876, 151.0284, 151.1808, 151.3332, 
151.4856, 151.638, 151.7904, 151.9428, 152.0952, 152.2476), DT = c(435.6977, 
437.6732, 441.4934, 444.6542, 445.771, 444.4603, 443.5679, 444.5042, 
447.3567, 450.4373), GR = c(13.8393, 14.549, 15.7866, 16.9114, 
18.4841, 18.8695, 17.7494, 16.7178, 12.8839, 11.7309)), .Names = c("DEPTH", 
"DT", "GR"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

(the full logs data file is much larger, so I don't quite know how to set it here for you to use. Instead I've taken a part of it that matches an interval in the next data set; `analyses`)

And some lower-res discrete numerical data, where depths are in ranges unequal to the `logs` data above. This data represents a sample interval of a given length at a specific depth range and does not vary along the given range:

```
analyses <-
structure(list(from = c(151L, 198L, 284L, 480L), to = c(151.1, 
198.1, 284.1, 480.1), TC = c(1.276476312, 1.383553608, 1.46771308, 
1.125049954), DEN = c(1.842555733, 1.911724824, 1.997592565, 
NA), PORO = c(50.21947697, 44.26392579, 39.31309757, NA)), .Names = c("from", 
"to", "TC", "DEN", "PORO"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

And some lower-res categorical data with data in unequal depth ranges:

```
units <-
structure(list(from = c(0, 100, 450, 535, 617.89), to = c(100, 
450, 535, 617.89, 619.25), strat = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("Formation A", "Formation B", 
"Group C", "Group D", "Unassigned"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("from", 
"to", "strat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The intended result is data at the resolution of the first data set `logs`, with merged data from the 2nd and 3rd. In this case it would result in this data frame:

```
DEPTH   DT  GR  TC  DEN PORO    Unit
150.8760    435.69  13.83   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
151.0284    437.67  14.54   1.27    1.84    50.21   Formation A
151.1808    441.49  15.78   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
151.3332    444.65  16.91   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
151.4856    445.77  18.48   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
151.6380    444.46  18.86   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
151.7904    443.56  17.74   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
151.9428    444.50  16.71   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
152.0952    447.35  12.88   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
152.2476    450.43  11.73   NA  NA  NA  Formation A
```

I tried merging the data frames, and then using na.approx to fill in the gaps, but the problem is that many of the variables in `logs` have NaNs or NAs that I don't want to interpolate values for -- they need to remain as NAs.

Comment: Please include the intended result.

Comment: Yes, should have put that in first time around. I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your data.frames with `merge`, or `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)

# If you know that each depth (in the first data.frame) 
# is in exactly one interval (in the second and third data.frames)
sqldf( "
  SELECT *
  FROM data A, analyses B, units C
  WHERE B.[from] <= A.DEPTH AND A.DEPTH < B.[to] -- Need to quote some of the column names
  AND   C.[from] <= A.DEPTH AND A.DEPTH < C.[to]
" )

# If each depth (in the first data.frame) 
# is in at most one interval (in the second and third data.frames)
sqldf( "
  SELECT *
  FROM data A
  LEFT JOIN analyses B ON B.[from] <= A.DEPTH AND A.DEPTH < B.[to]
  LEFT JOIN units    C ON C.[from] <= A.DEPTH AND A.DEPTH < C.[to]
  ORDER BY DEPTH
" )
```

Comment: This looks really useful, but I am on R 2.14, and need 2.15 for dependencies, so haven't been able to try it yet. Will attempt to upgrade... and let you know.

Comment: Yep, that second query does it. Excellent, thanks. Have never joined to a range before.